# I can not add hibernate in intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ to hibernate but it does add error.

I follow video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGl4u44WRiI

this error:

> [2016-05-16 07:44:21] javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] class or package not found
>
> [2016-05-16 07:44:21] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   models.PmaExportTemplates

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I noticed about intellij is if you import the hibernate from the project structure to include support.  You don't get all the files required.  I am not sure what you are trying to do if you are wanting to use JPA and hibernate as a provider, then I would download hibernate separately from hibernate.org and put the lib -> required folder contents and JPA folder content into its own folder along with what jdbc driver you would be using.  Ex: SQL, MYSQL ect.  If you are wanting to use the function in intellij you also have to provide a persistance.xml file and Java EE persistance support.  I would suggest if you are just wanting to save something using hibernate that you download the files as said and then create the hibernate library when you make the project.  If you want to avoid using EntityManagerFactory and use native hibernate API then you would be using hibernate.cfg.xml and a (class).hbm.xml mapping file or JPA annotations in the source code.  I would suggest using SessionFactory and configure that full support of hibernate.  Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really help with the error your getting seems like it is not mapping the class.  I usually manually type out the entity classes so I think you are getting the error from creating from templates.  I will have to try to make a database schema and use the template feature.  Perhaps I have been doing it the really long way.  Sorry I could not be of assistance.